# Query Error with IN operator must be used with an iterable expression

Tags: apex, soql, query, process-builder, invocable-method

I am trying to pass multiple variables from Process Builder to my Apex Class, and eventually manipulate those values to update fields in the Account object.

The below code produces this error message:

> Query Error with IN operator must be used with an iterable expression

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

```
public class ProcessHandlerShowAccounts {
    public class AccountParameter{
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public Id accountId;
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String name;
    }
    @InvocableMethod(label='handleNewAccounts' description='Reconstitue the Accounts being inserted based on the variables passed from Process Builder')
    public static void handleNewAccounts(AccountParameter[] accountParameters) {
        Accountparameter a;
        //Error IN operator must be used with an iterable expression
        List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Name FROM Account Where Id in : a.accountId];
        for(account ac: accounts){
            ac.Alias__c = a.name;
        }
        upsert accounts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error's phrasing is slightly opaque, but it points squarely to the issue here. When you use `IN` in SOQL, you must provide some kind of collection. That can be a literal list written out, like `IN ('001XXXXXXXXXXXX', '001XXXXXXXXXXXY', ...)`, or it can be a binding to an Apex set or list variable, like `IN :mySetVariable`.

What it can't be is a bind, like here, to a single Id value. For that use case, just use `=`:

```
SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :a.accountId
```

Note also, though, that if you run this code you're going to get a `NullPointerException` because you have not initialized `a`.

If what you're trying to do is query any Account whose Id is in one of the `AccountParameter` records passed to this method, you'll need to create a `Set<Id>` and loop over the records to add their account Ids to that set. Then you can use your query as written, because you have a Set to bind to - that's an iterable collection.

Comment: Thank you but is there an easier way to take values passed to the invocablemethod to pass to a webservice?

Comment: That's maybe a bigger question than I can answer in a comment, and without seeing the code involved.

Comment: do you have a reference i could read?

Comment: also in my ref above.  the code for(AccountParameter a : accountParameters) accounts.add(new Account(Id=a.accountId,Name=a.name));    how would i access the variables to get the value?

Comment: I'm sorry, @nameishi, I may be a little confused tonight but I don't really follow the question. Which value(s)?

Comment: http://leehildebrand.name/?p=223 . how would i access/use the values of a.accountId & a.name ?  i want to be able to use these values to update records.

Comment: Well, I'm not Lee Hildebrand and I honestly find that article a bit confusing/odd, but you're getting a list of `AccountParameter` objects in your method. You can loop through those just like you do with `accounts` as you wrote it (`for (AccountParameter ap : accountParameters) {`).

Comment: Then, inside that loop, you can access `ap.accountId` and `ap.name`, and use them as you please - whether to create new Account instances and update them into the database, or to pass into other code.

Comment: lol i know you're not Lee Hildebrand but how he instantiates AccountParameter is confusing.  Would I say for (AccountParameter a : accountParamters) {   a.accountId;  a.name }